# Determine whether $\frac{K\left(\sqrt{1-x^2}\right)^2}{K(x)^2}$ is positive rational (given $x$)

Tags: cv.complex-variables, modular-forms, class-field-theory, elliptic-integrals

Denote the complete elliptic integral of the first kind by
$$K(x)=\int_0^{\pi /2}\frac{d\varphi}{\sqrt{1-x^2\sin^2\varphi}}$$
and
$$f(x)=\frac{K\left(\sqrt{1-x^2}\right)^2}{K(x)^2}$$

**Question:**
Given a real $x$, $0\lt x\lt 1$, is there an algorithm which determines whether $f(x)$ is positive rational?

**Thoughts:**
Let $\lambda^*(x)=\sqrt{\lambda (i\sqrt{x})}$ where $\lambda$ is the modular lambda function:
$$\lambda (x)=\left(\frac{\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty e^{\pi i x\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)^2}}{\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty e^{\pi ixn^2}}\right)^4$$
It turns out that $\lambda^*$ is the inverse of $f$:
$$\lambda^*(f(x))=x,\quad f(\lambda^*(x))=x$$

It is known that $\lambda^*(f(x))$ is algebraic if $f(x)$ is positive rational. Equivalently, $x$ is algebraic if $f(x)$ is positive rational. By contrapositive,

> If $x$ is not algebraic, then $f(x)$ is not positive rational.

So, a part of the problem is already solved. It remains to solve

> If $x$ is algebraic, can we determine whether $f(x)$ is positive rational?

The answer is known for *some* algebraic $x$, for example
$$f\left((\sqrt{10}-3)(\sqrt{2}+1)^2\right)=\frac{2}{5}.$$

This question was also asked on MSE (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4247055/determine-whether-frack-left-sqrt1-x2-right2kx2-is-positive-rati).